# select where columnx is less than multiple columns based on row value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
ID Company   value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6
1  companyb  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
2  companyb  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
3  companyb  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
4  companya  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
5  companya  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
6  companya  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
7  companya  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
8  companyc  xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx   xxxx
```

I want to

```
select * 
from data_set 
where company="companyb" 
and value1 < value2, value3, value4, value5, or value6
```

In the next step of the learning process the name of the value columns is the same as the values in the `Company column`. I:e `value1` is named `companyb` and `value2` is named `companya`. Can I fetch all rows where companies values are lower than at least one other company' value? Or do I have to search for each company one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check if a value is smaller than *any* of a set of values, just compare against the largest of those values:

```
SELECT ... WHERE value1 < max(value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)
```

Comment: Works! Possible to use value of company column to decide which value-column to check against max(of others)? @dasblinkenlight, result returns rows where at least one other company value is lower. not all.

Comment: That would be another question. (And I am unable to understand what you want to do; better show an example.)